# Running I/O operations more than CPU count

Tags: concurrency, io

Let's say I have 2 CPUs in my server and running 10 async I/O operations (sending HTTP request). If  each request takes 1 second, with Promise.all I got all the result in about 1s. But I have only 2 CPUs. How all these 10 requests runs in paralel and I get result in 1 second. Theoretically, it should take 5 seconds reducing load 2 times. Can anybody explain this to me.

Comment: Why would you need an entire CPU to wait for a HTTP request to respond?

Comment: Network requests aren't CPU-bound but bound by the network speed. The CPU time needed to handle them should be negligible.

Comment: Don't thing only HTPP requests, any type of I/O operation, question is that, how 2 CPUs can process more than 2 thing at a time.

Comment: Virtual cores have been around for over a decade, for a start... Also, *again*, network requests don't need CPU. Why would you think they do?

Comment: But most of the time CPU doesn't do anything during I/O operations. It just has to wait for them to finish. Surely it's easy to imagine that doing nothing multiple times at the time same time isn't very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any modern system, your CPU doesn't have to be involved the majority of time the I/O takes, it just has to be involved periodically to grab the data that's been received in a buffer by the I/O subsystem or provide the I/O subsystem a buffer data to be sent. The rest of the time it can be doing other things. Even the I/O subsystem may not need to be doing that much work if there's a lot of waiting involved (as there is in network operations and actual hard-disk I/O [less so for SSDs]).

Comment: That means we can send unlimited requests and it does not depend on CPU count?

Comment: @ElmirBabakishiyev - Nothing in computers is unlimited. Eventually you'll saturate the capacity of your system, whether that's the CPU, the I/O infrastructure, etc.

Comment: So count of simultaneous requests depend on I/O subsystem, instead of count of CPUs which only involved getting processed data from this subsystem.

Comment: @ElmirBabakishiyev - I/O subsystem, available memory to the processor, limits set by the environment you're running in (for instance, most browsers limit the number of truly concurrent HTTP connections), ...